# Using Date() in a 12-Hour Time Device

Tags: ios, swift, date

Was trying to use the current date with Date() and making some operation on it.

```
print("Date() -> ", Date())
```

[image]

When the device is on a 24-Hour Time mode:

> Date() -> 2018-07-10 09:06:38 +0000

When the device is on a 12-Hour Time mode:

> Date() -> 2018-07-10 99:04:09 AM +0000

Is this normal to have **99:04:09** for the 12-Hour Time mode? If yes, how do you manage your operations depending on the Hour Time mode?

Comment: `99:04:09`, that's weird :(

Comment: yes I agree, it's just in a viewDidLoad of a UIViewController

Comment: Very strange, have you tried to change the time zone to another location?

Comment: Yes I tried, work perfectly on 24-Hour Time mode but not on 12

Comment: you should make your calendrical operations using the date object not the string. If you need a date string properly formatted thats not sensible to the user device's settings or locale,  you need to use DateFormatter and set its locale to `"en_US_POSIX"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to convert Date() into string with the below code and check what you are getting in 12hour date formate.

You can convert **Date()** into a device's date formate as per below code.

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
formatter.dateStyle = .short
formatter.timeStyle = .short
let dateString = formatter.string(from: Date())// it will print date in device's current date formate style.
```

For more reference on dateStyle/timeStyle refer this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/46668669/3705770

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    // initially set the format based on your datepicker date
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    let myString = formatter.string(from: myDate)
    // convert your string to date
    let yourDate = formatter.date(from: myString)
    //then again set the date format whhich type of output you need
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy"
    // again convert your date to string
    let myStringafd = formatter.string(from: yourDate!)
```